# putty.exe, it cannot register any key stroke that I type in

Tags: keyboard, serial-port, putty

I am using the correct baud rate, correct COM, and right USB-to-serial driver and when I reboot the device I am able to see the text, but PuTTY is not recognizing any of my keyboard strokes. It was working perfect until now.

Can anyone help?

Comment: *"putty is not recognizing any of my keyboard strokes'* -- Do you mean you're not seeing the characters echoed (on the terminal display)?  Have you set up for *local* echo, or is the device (on the other end of the serial link) supposed to echo your input?

Comment: @sawdust  Nope my keyboard stroke were not identified. I resolved i t by changing the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main release for not being able to have keystroke is if the Serial to USB is broken.
If not all ports are working the we landup in this issue.

and Yes XON/XOFF will help.

If Using Windows Keyboard use the configuration below.
It resolved my problem.
[image: Putty.png]

My issue is solved.

Comment: Connecting to Linux embedded device: Using exactly the same settings but doesn't work for me. I see the characters in the terminal window but can't access the console. But I am able to access the shell via LAN.

But on a Linux desktop using minicom it works ... so the board itself doesn't seem to be the issue ... Seems to be a Windows/PuTTY issue.

Answer (score 9):

Have you looked at the flow control?  Try using XON/XOFF or maybe none and see if that doesn't get it working for you.

Comment: Up voted because turning Flow Control under Serial options from XON/XOFF to None fixed my keyboard issue on an ESP8266 PyBoard.

Answer (score 0):

[My window configuration yet keyboard not working on Putty App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp7Sm.png)

Keys configuration for my PC windows is already set as recommended above. Still keyboard keys are not displayed (or entered) in the Putty App.